# filtering an array and counting the number of elements

Tags: swift

I am trying to count the number of items in an array which correspond to a particular attribute.

```
func subCount() {
    let arr = subDS.subFolders // array
    var counts: [String: Int] = [:]

    arr.forEach { counts[$0.parentFolder!, default: 0] += 1 }

    print(Array(counts.values))

}
```

when the code above is executed, if the count is zero it does not appear in the array. Also the order of the array formed in an incorrect order.

Comment: "Also the order of the array formed in an incorrect order." Because `counts` is a Dictionary, it's not ordered. So `counts.values` doesn't respect any order.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to filter on, maybe you could add some sample data

Comment: You should define `subDS.subFolders` and the `parentFolder` property. "if the count is zero it does not appear in the array" doesn't make sense. Do show your real code, so that we could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter) 
for example :

```
    var filterArray = subDS.subFolders.filter { $0. parentFolder == 0 }
    let count = filterArray.count
```

The first $0 is from the filter and it represents each subFolders.

Comment: What does it mean that parentFolder == 0?

Comment: Its mean the attribute of the object that i want to compare with

Comment: But 0 (zero), what does that mean? I would guess parentFolder is a string or an url.

Comment: First there is an extra space after `$0.`, second the keys of `counts` are strings, so they can't be compared to integers